# Por que está dando esse erro e como faço para reverter isso?

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho essa tabela:

```
create table lagoa_azul(
id_lagoa_azul int not null auto_increment, 
sem_epi int not null,
p1 smallint,
p2 smallint,
p3 smallint,
p4 smallint,
p5 smallint, 
p6 smallint,  
p7 smallint,
p8 smallint,
p9 smallint,
totOvos int,
pend tinyint,
ext tinyint,
ipo decimal(5,1),
ido decimal(5,1),
ano varchar(4),
primary key(id_lagoa_azul)
) default charset = utf8;
```

e esse trigger:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER IpoIdoLagoaAzul before insert ON lagoa_azul
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare nump int;
    declare tovos int;

    set @nump := (select count(nullif(new.p1, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p2, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p3, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p4, 0))
+ count(nullif(new.p5, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p6, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p7, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p8, 0)) + count(nullif(new.p9, 0)) from lagoa_azul where sem_epi= new.sem_epi);

    set @tovos = new.p1+new.p2+new.p3+new.p4+new.p5+new.p6+new.p7+new.p8+new.p9;

    set new.ipo = (@nump/9)*100;
    set new.ido = @tovos/@nump; 

END; //
delimiter ;
```

Quando executo um INSERT INTO eu tenho esse erro:

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

INSERT INTO `databaseentomo1.2`.`lagoa_azul` (`sem_epi`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`, `p6`, `p7`, `p8`, `p9`, `pend`, `ext`, `ano`) VALUES ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2018');

ERROR 1365: 1365: Division by 0
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `databaseentomo1.2`.`lagoa_azul` (`sem_epi`, `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4`, `p5`, `p6`, `p7`, `p8`, `p9`, `pend`, `ext`, `ano`) VALUES ('1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '0', '0', '0', '2018')
```

Comment: A sua variável `@nump` está ficando com o valor `0` em algum caso.

Comment: @Sorack Seria no "select count"? teria alguma maneira de atribuir o valor desse select a variável?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi, a variável `@numb` pode ser zero, dando erro ao executar o comando `@tovos/@nump`. Melhor seria verificar antes dessa operação o valor do `@numb`.

Outra melhoria que você pode fazer no seu `INSERT` seria trocar os valores em aspas para valores inteiros, respeitando o `TYPE` das colunas.

Comment: Toquei os valores para inteiros como sugerido, mas continua com o mesmo erro. Vou verificar o valor do @nump. Obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema fazendo uso de uma função dentro do trigger.

a FUNCTION:

```
delimiter //
create function numpAlecrim (p1 int, p2 int, p3 int, p4 int, p5 int, p6 int, p7 int, p8 int, p9 int) returns int

begin
    declare nump int default 0;

    if p1<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p2<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p3<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p4<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p5<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p6<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p7<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p8<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;
    if p9<>0 then set nump := nump+1;
    end if;    
    return nump;
end //
delimiter ;
```

E fiz pequenas alterações no TRIGGER:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER IpoIdoLagoaAzul before insert ON lagoa_azul
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN       
    set @tovos = new.p1+new.p2+new.p3+new.p4+new.p5+new.p6+new.p7+new.p8+new.p9;

    select numpAlecrim(new.p1,new.p2,new.p3,new.p4,new.p5,new.p6,new.p7,new.p8,new.p9) into @nump;

    set new.totOvos = @tovos;
    set new.ipo = (@nump/9)*100;
    set new.ido = @tovos/@nump; 

END; //
delimiter ;
```

Se tiverem alguma sugestão de código mais simplificada, principalmente na função, ficarei bastante agradecido!